# Ansible, how to access variables which were imported from a file?

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I have a yml file (cert_expiring.yml) that I'm generating in my playbook and it consists of a dictionary of IDs and server names of servers whose SSL certs are expiring.

Ex: cert_expiring.yml

```
myDict:
    705:node1.corp.com
    670:node2.corp.com
    1163:node3.corp.com
    715:node4.corp.com
```

I have a play that is reading in this file and storing it inside a variable called "expired_certs":

```
- name: Store file contents into variable
      include_vars:
        file: cert_expiring.yml
        name: expired_certs
```

The contents of "expired_certs" looks like this:

```
{
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [{
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "backup": "",
            "changed": true,
            "diff": [{
                    "after": "",
                    "after_header": "./cert_expiring.txt (content)",
                    "before": "",
                    "before_header": "./cert_expiring.txt (content)"
                },
                {
                    "after_header": "./cert_expiring.txt (file attributes)",
                    "before_header": "./cert_expiring.txt (file attributes)"
                }
            ],
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "attributes": null,
                    "backrefs": false,
                    "backup": false,
                    "content": null,
                    "create": true,
                    "delimiter": null,
                    "dest": "./cert_expiring.txt",
                    "directory_mode": null,
                    "firstmatch": false,
                    "follow": false,
                    "force": null,
                    "group": null,
                    "insertafter": null,
                    "insertbefore": null,
                    "line": "    705:node1.corp.com",
                    "mode": null,
                    "owner": null,
                    "path": "./cert_expiring.txt",
                    "regexp": null,
                    "remote_src": null,
                    "selevel": null,
                    "serole": null,
                    "setype": null,
                    "seuser": null,
                    "src": null,
                    "state": "present",
                    "unsafe_writes": null,
                    "validate": null
                }
            },
            "item": {
                "cn": "node1.corp.com",
                "expires": "2020-11-05T15:20:18+00:00",
                "id": 705,
                "serial": "1111"
            },
            "msg": "line added"
        }]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to follow the same procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478893/ansible-how-to-query-deeply-nested-json-keys/67562026#67562026) to reference "cn", "expires", "id", and "serial" from the nested json but not sure why its not working.

This is my play to access those elements:

```
- name: Print expired_certs variable contents
      debug:
        msg: "{{ expired_certs | json_query('results.item[*].{expires: expires, cn: cn, serial: serial, id: id}') }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

Also, tried this:

```
msg: "{{ expired_certs | json_query('results.[*].{expires: item.expires, cn: item.cn, serial: item.serial, id: itme.id}') }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "cn": null,
        "expires": null,
        "id": null,
        "serial": null
    }
}
```

Need help understanding how to access nested elements.

Comment: *but not sure why its not working* > Can you elaborate, what is not working? Is it not giving you the data you expect? Or giving you nothing at all? Or erroring?

Comment: i updated the question with the outputs of each play.

Comment: You'll also want to be cautious because `705:node1.corp.com` is not a yaml mapping from `705` to `node1...` it's a _single scalar_ of `705:node1.corp.com` (as one can see referenced in the debug output); you'll want `705: node1.corp.com` or if you require the keys to be `str`, then `"705": node1.corp.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your JSON, the key `results` is a list, not a dictionary:

```json
{
  "results": [{
    "changed": true,
    "...cut": "for brevity"
  }]
}
```

<sup>In JSON, square brackets indicate array (or list to speak Ansible language)</sup>

And the key `item` is a dictionary, not a list:

```json
{
  "item": {
    "cn": "node1.corp.com",
    "expires": "2020-11-05T15:20:18+00:00",
    "id": 705,
    "serial": "1111"
  }
}
```

<sup>In JSON, curly brackets indicate objects (or dictionary to speak Ansible language)</sup>

So, your [wildcard expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#wildcards) is just laying on the wrong key.

It should be:

```
results[*].item
```

As opposed yo your actual:

```
results.item[*]
```

And also, because the `item` key does already contains only the information you need, you don't need to go the extra mile and redo an object. You can stay with `results[*].item`.

Ending up with:

```yaml
- name: Print expired_certs variable contents
  debug:
    msg: "{{ expired_certs | json_query('results[*].item') }}"
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. i have a related question...if i want to take only 2 items from `results[*].item` and store them in a separate variable, then i would need to "redo an object" correct? for example if i want to store id and cn inside of **desiredData** i would do this correct?
```set_fact:
        desiredData: "{{ expired_certs | json_query('results[*].item.{id: id, cn: cn}') }}"```

Comment: Correct then, indeed